# How can I predict whether a key_pressed event will be followed by a key_typed event?

Tags: java, keyevent

I need to capture key events (chars, shift, arrows...) and forward them to another device.
I can listen to `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASE` events for this.
However, I want to listen also to `KEY_TYPED`, so that I already get the unicode chars according to the configured keyboard.

I have this program:

```
package keyboard2AndroidUSB;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Keyboard2AndroidUSB extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Keyboard");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Label(), 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> System.out.println("KEY_PRESSED, code: " + e.getCode()));
        scene.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent e) -> System.out.println("KEY_RELEASED, code: " + e.getCode()));
        scene.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent e) -> System.out.println("KEY_TYPED, char: " + e.getCharacter()));

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

If I press shift, then press right, then release shift and then release shift,
I get exactly the events that I need to forward to the other device.

```
KEY_PRESSED, code: SHIFT
KEY_PRESSED, code: RIGHT
KEY_RELEASED, code: RIGHT
KEY_RELEASED, code: SHIFT
```

Pressing the key '8', I get these three events.
Here I would need to forward the `KEY_TYPED` event to the other device, but discard the `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events.
(so that the other device only handles one '8', not two)

```
KEY_PRESSED, code: DIGIT8
KEY_TYPED, char: 8
KEY_RELEASED, code: DIGIT8
```

To type the ')' character in my Swiss French keyboard, I need to press Shift + 8.
Doing so, I get these five events.
Here I would need to forward the `KEY_TYPED` event ')', and optionally the `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events for the `SHIFT` code,
but I would definitively need to discard the `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events for the DIGIT8 code.
(because the system has already interpreted this sequence according to the keyboard configuration, and my other device already gets the `KEY_TYPED` event)

```
KEY_PRESSED, code: SHIFT
KEY_PRESSED, code: DIGIT8
KEY_TYPED, char: (
KEY_RELEASED, code: DIGIT8
KEY_RELEASED, code: SHIFT
```

---

So, when I get a `KEY_PRESSED` event, how can I predict whether I will also receive a `KEY_TYPED` event or not?
(then I could decide to forward or discard that `KEY_PRESSED` event)

ps: I cannot wait to receive the `KEY_RELEASED` event in order to decide, because holding a key for a while it will produce many `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_TYPED` according to the speed keyboard configuration, and only one `KEY_RELEASED` when done.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of the problem is naive,  but would you not have to define a set of 'modifier keys' and a set of 'character keys' and then enumerate the combinations that DO NOT produce valid key typed events? eg: if the current keys pressed are `shift + z`, we can say we will get a key typed. if the current keys are `ctrl + z` we won't?

Comment: that depends on the keyboard configuration. i cannot know in advance.

Comment: basically, i want to port a part of this application written in web/javascript to java: https://github.com/IvanVolosyuk/wifikeyboard/blob/master/html/key.html

Comment: ohh i got it. basically, i only need to forward key_pressed events with "control" codes, so codes from 1 to 47, except 32 (blank space). and discard the rest key_pressed events.